# send data to rabbitmq in magento 2.1 EE

Tags: magento-2.1

I have installed rabbitmq on my server. Now want test the rabbitmq, how do i do that, want to send some sample text and see does it saved in rabbitmq. And also want to get response from it.

Comment: Did you get something on this ?

Comment: Do you still need help?

Comment: yes tell me how to do that